# Apollo cache update is not reflected on paginated query

Tags: apollo-client, react-apollo

I have two components, one of the components creates new items, the other one displays them using an "infinite scroll list". These two components do not have a parent/child relationship and they're not rendered at the same time (they're on different "pages").

I've followed [these docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#include-modified-objects-in-mutation-responses) and included the modified object in the mutation of my first component. And I can see the new object in the Apollo cache using dev tools. (`Car:<some UUID>` gets added in the cache after the mutation runs)

My paginated component is configured with [relay style pagination](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/cursor-based/#relay-style-cursor-pagination), and the pagination works fine, but when I add a new item it doesn't appear in the list until I refresh the page.

My InMemoryCache looks like this:

```json
    ...
    typePolicies: {
      // paginated results
      Query: {
        fields: {
          cars: relayStylePagination()
        }
      },
      CarsResult: {
        fields: {
          edges: {
            // Concatenate the incoming list items with
            // the existing list items.
            merge(existing = [], incoming) {
              return [...existing, ...incoming]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      PageInfo: {
        fields: {
          endCursor: {
            merge(existing, incoming) {
              return incoming
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The mutation looks like this:

```
  ${CAR_SUMMARY_FRAGMENT}
  mutation CreateCar($name: String!) {
    createCar(
      input: {
        name: $name
      }
    ) {
      ...CarSummary
    }
  }
```

The `CreateCar` return type is `Car`

Then my paginated query:

```
  query CarsPaginated($after: Cursor) {
    cars(
      page: { first: 25, after: $after }
      orderBy: { field: CREATE_TIME, direction: DESC }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          ...CarSummary
        }
      }
      totalCount
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
    }
  }
```

The `CarsPaginated` return type is `CarsResult`:

```
type CarsResult {
  edges: [CarEdge]
  pageInfo: PageInfo!
  totalCount: Int!
}

type CarEdge {
  node: Car
  cursor: Cursor!
}
```

Ideally, I'd like the new item to show up at the top of my items list on the other component.

- I've tried to use the "refetchQueries" attribute but the paginated query is not active since the list component is not rendered at that time.

Maybe there's something I need to do in the typePolicies?